# Are there any debates about the presence of entire words in Scripture?

Tags: tanach, machlokes

Besides for the odd letter, such as an extra Vov or Yud, what Scriptual verses that we would find in Tanach today, were once or still debated by Halachic Authorities as to what is the correct text. Or has the text of the Chumash and Nach always been clear as day as to what the exact text is?

To be clear, an entire word must be missing or added to satisfy the above.

For some background why I am asking this question, please see my other question: [Did Mesushelach survive the flood according to any sources?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109418/did-mesushelach-survive-the-flood-according-to-any-sources)

Comment: Consider linking a source for "the odd letter, such as an extra Vov or Yud"

Comment: By far the best example here is in Joshua 21:"36-37"

Comment: My Koren Tanach has an extra "optional"  verse in at least one location. Divrei HaYomim, IIRC.